# passing a list of objects from jsf page to another

Tags: jsf-2

I am new at JavaServer Faces (JSF).

I have a list of cars and after pressing the `commandButton` of my first page I want to show the list in the other page (the backing beans are `RequestScoped`).

I have seen examples where you can only pass `String` values.

Comment: You want to open the other page after pressing the commandButton ?

Comment: no i want to show the result of my action method(wich is a list of cars) in another page

Answer (score 1):

if you have list of cars, it means you have data table or some another list which is coming from managed beans. if you want show whole list in the next page, you need just call the same list from next page.
if you want pass only one row /object, you should pass row/item id via f:param , in the next page from another managed bean you should handle id and call from database getItemById(id) and in the page show item.

Comment: and how call i the list please?

Comment: please have a look at http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html